# Initialize addheaders as global in okhttpClient

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp, fast-android-networking

As I need to initialize add headers as global to get headers in all API call, I have tried but while debug its not sending the headers in API call.

```
         val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .authenticator { _, response ->
                    response.request().newBuilder().addHeader(
                        "authorization","123").build()
                }
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
        AndroidNetworking.initialize(applicationContext, client)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace your code with mentioned below and try again

```
OkHttpClient.Builder().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
            }
        })
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
    AndroidNetworking.initialize(applicationContext, client)
```

Comment: Thanks Updated ., but still while debug its not get the header in API call in mHeadersMap as size is 0, - @jayesh gurudayalani

Comment: Can you share your updated code please

Comment: Sorry bhai., API is working, but only the value its not Woking

Comment: Now its Fine ,., thanks for your time @jayesh gurudayalani